# How to inherit "Manager().list" in python?

Tags: python, list, inheritance, multiprocessing

I've implemented my own "DataSet" class which inherited from list and I need to port that code to run in multiprocessing mode. Here is a sample of my class:

```
class DataSet(list):
    @property
    def n_training(self):
        return len(self) * 0.8
    @property
    def n_validation(self):
        return len(self) * 0.2
```

Beside creating an instance of "Manager().list" in this class, are there any more simple way to do this like:

```
from multiprocessing import Manager
class DataSet(Manager().list):
```

Please note that "Manager().list" is the representation of

```
manager = Manager()
manager.list()
```

Comment: `Manager` being [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.sharedctypes.multiprocessing.Manager)?

Comment: @Lattyware: Part of the multiprocessing package.

Comment: The multiprocessing list type is a proxy; you'll have to study the [`managers.py` source](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/multiprocessing/managers.py) to see what you can subclass there, and you probably need to register the type with the manager. It should be possible though.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I thought that this type of question is very common and I'd be surprised if I have to solve it in a complicated way.

Comment: @JessadaThutkawkorapin: No, I don't think it is common, actually. And the `SyncManager.register()` class method is not documented, so the package authors did not (yet) expect this to be a use case they needed to cover.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, actually, `SyncManager` inherits from `BaseManager`, which has a documented [`register`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.register) class method.

Comment: @senderle: cool, I stand corrected then.

Comment: @senderle,@MartijnPieters: I'm going to try if your idea can help !!!

Comment: @JessadaThutkawkorapin, I've never done this myself, so I won't post it as an answer, but [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers) example shows how to use a subclass of `BaseManager` to register a custom type. It seems to be pretty simple; testing it now.

Comment: @senderle: I am trying on that. Thx to your 'register','basemanager' keywords above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the suggestion from @senderle and @Martijn Pieters, I managed to get [a solution](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#customized-managers)

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseProxy

class DataSetClass(list):
    @property
    def n_training(self):
        return len(self) * 0.8
    @property
    def n_validation(self):
        return len(self) * 0.2

class DataSetProxy(BaseProxy):
    _exposed_ = ('append', '__len__')
    def append(self, item):
        return self._callmethod('append', item)
    def __len__(self):
        return self._callmethod('__len__')

class MyManager(BaseManager):
    pass

MyManager.register('DataSet', DatasetClass, DataSetProxy)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()
    dataset = manager.DataSet()
    dataset.append('item1')
    dataset.append('item2')
    print len(dataset)
```